# In Chrome, how do I get to the recently used tab?

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

Say I've got many tabs open and I'm doing something on one of them. I now open a new tab (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

I do some work there and then need to return to the previously viewed tab. How do I do that in Chrome?

Comment: There are 2 ways I currently know of - Ctrl+tabbing through all of the tabs until I find the right one, or using a mouse and trying to select which I think was the right one. Both ways are terrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a native keyboard shortcut to do it in Chrome, but there is an extension that (sort of) adds functionality to do this:

> **[Recent Tabs Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/recent-tabs/ocllfmhjhfmogablefmibmjcodggknml)**
>   Cycle through your most recently used tabs (MRU) like Alt+Tab, but, with the shortcut keys Ctrl+Q or Ctrl+`(~) or assign your own!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The way I usually do it:

(not helpful for filling our forms though.)
Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> to open the new tab. Do your stuff.
Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> to close the tab.

This takes you back to the tab you were on when you switched.

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> to reopen the tab if you need to.

Alternately when I have to deal with a form:

Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> for a new window then <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> between them. (I know some people have a negative feeling about new windows but for what you're doing it may just be a good solution to try getting used to.)